# In the given circuit of a regulated power supply, why is error computed twice, i.e., before and after isolation?

Tags: power-supply, pwm, opto-isolator, power-electronics

[image: Regulated Power supply with isolation]

**Circuit Operation**
\$R_4\$ and \$R_5\$ constitute the potential divider which is fed to the error amplifier \$A_1\$. The reference voltage is generated by the Zener diode \$Z_1\$. The error signal is fed to the controller using an opto-coupler. The + and - in the controller indicates the corresponding terminals of the error amplifier inside the PWM IC.

**Question**
Why does this circuit compute error twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. A1 at the secondary side computes the error, and transfers it to the primary side using the optocoupler, which is used to pull the Vref lower, to decrease the activity of the PWM circuit, which closes the loop. At the primary side, there is no comparing to any reference volatge, and the operation (coupling factor) of the optocouple is so variable that it would not make sense anyway.

What might confuse you is that OC1 interfaces to the PWM circuit via its Vref output. This is just a way of gradually shutting down the PWM circuit.

Comment: It should be "At the primary side, there is no comparing..." right? Still I'm now confused as to what the R1/R2 feedback to `+` and the RL feedback to `-` is used for, don't know if that is for interest of the OP, but maybe you can comment on that?

Comment: Correct, and I mistyped secondary :) As for the rest: I don't know.

Comment: My thinking was that the collector current through the RL would be used as a negative feedback and the R1/R2 divided Vref as a positive input to the PWM regulation. This configuration is uncommon and requires a high linearity optocoupler and a Vref capable of driving the currents, but wouldn't that be an option as well? Maybe the textbook (presumably) author thought that this might be less confusing than the common method you describe.

Comment: I think you might well be correct, and the effect on the PWM is due to rising the voltage of the - input rather than lowering the Vref. But still that is all part of a feedback loop, so linearity is not required.